# Continuity of analytic function implies convergence of power series?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic in the unit disk $\Delta:\,|z|<1$. Then $f(z)$ has a Taylor series $\sum=\sum a_nz^n$ in the unit disk. One may assume that $\sum$ has $R=1$ as its radius of convergence for convenience.

Question 1 (local version):  If $f(z)$   is continous at some point, say $z=1$, on the unit circle $S^1$, then its Taylor series $\sum$  is  covergent at $z=1$?

Question 2 (global version):  Suppose that  $f(z)$   is continous on the closed unit disk $\overline\Delta$.  Is the  Taylor series $\sum$ covergent at every poin of $S^1$?

Of course, if the answer to the local version is "yes", then so is the answer to the global version.

EDIT. It seems that  Question 1 obviously has a negative answer. So I modify it into a new question.

Question 3 (New local version):  Suppose that  $f(z)$   is continous at some point, say $z=1$, on the unit circle $S^1$ and the coefficients of $\sum$ satisfies $a_n\to 0$.  Is the Taylor series $\sum$  covergent at $z=1$?

Note. If $f$ is analytic at $z=1$, then the answer to Question 3 is yes. This is Fatou's Theorem.

Comment: For Question 3, $a_n=O(1/n)$ [would suffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem#Littlewood.27s_extension_of_Tauber.27s_theorem) and my impression is that the order of magnitude cannot be improved, but I don't remember ever seeing an example to this effect.

Comment: Congratulations on being the [100,000th question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8289/29966) on MSE :P

Comment: At the time the 100,000th question was posted, a sreenshot was taken: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sslH5.jpg

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to Question 2 is no. The essential reason is the following: Du Bois - Reymond constructed a continuous function $f$ on the unit circle whose Fourier series, $\sum_n a_n e^{i n \theta}$, does not converge at $\theta=0$. If you look at the construction, you'll see that it is easy to arrange that $a_n=0$ for $n<0$. Then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ defines an analytic function inside the unit disc, which extends continuously to the boundary, but such that $\sum a_n$ is divergent.

Below, I give the details. I used [Pinsky's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=tlLE4KUkk1gC&lpg=PA73&ots=KL2v8l98Af&dq=du%20Bois%E2%80%93Reymond%20gourier%20counterexample&pg=PA74#v=onepage&q=du%20Bois%E2%80%93Reymond%20gourier%20counterexample&f=false) as my reference for the construction of du Bois - Reymond.

---

Define $S_M(z) = \sum_{r=1}^M \frac{z^r-z^{-r}}{r}$. Our function will be of the form
$$f(z) := \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{N_k}}{k^2} S_{M_k}(z) \quad (1)$$
where $M_k$ and $N_k$ are sequences of positive integers chosen such that 
$$0 < N_1 - M_1 < N_1 + M_1 < N_2 - M_2 < N_2 + M_2 < N_3 - M_3 < N_3+ M_3 < \cdots \quad (2)$$
and
$$\frac{\log M_k}{k^2} \to \infty \ \mbox{as} \ k \to \infty. \quad (3)$$

We will show below that the sum (1) is uniformly convergent in the closed unit disc. Hence, it defines a continuous function on the closed disc and an analytic function in the interior. Condition (2) forces that the polynomials $z^{N_k} s_{M_k}(z)$ have no overlapping terms, so the Taylor series of $f$ just looks like blocks of $-1/M_k$, $-1/(M_k-1)$, ..., $-1$, $0$, $1$, $1/2$, ..., $1/M_k$, separated by long blocks of zeroes. Define $a_n$ to be the coefficients of $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$.

We now check that $\sum a_n$ is divergent. We have 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N_k} a_n = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{j^2} \left( \frac{-1}{M_j} + \cdots + \frac{-1}{1} + \frac{1}{1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{M_j} \right) - \frac{1}{k^2} \left( \frac{1}{M_k} + \frac{1}{M_k -1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{1} \right)$$
$$=0+0+\cdots + 0  - \frac{1}{k^2} \left( \frac{1}{M_k} + \frac{1}{M_k -1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{1} \right) \approx - \frac{\log M_k}{k^2}.$$
Using condition (3), this goes to $- \infty$. So there is a subsequence of partial sums of $\sum a_n$ which goes to $- \infty$ and $\sum a_n$ diverges.

---

We now must prove that (1) is uniformly convergent. We need

**Lemma** There is an absolute constant $C$ so that, for any real angle $\theta$, and any positive integer $M$, we have
$$\left| \sum_{r=1}^M \frac{\sin (r \theta)}{r} \right| \leq C.$$

Given the lemma, uniform convergence is easy. By the maximum modulus principle, $\left| z^{N_k} s_{M_k}(z) \right|$ is maximized on the boundary of the unit disc.
On that boundary, $|e^{i N_k \theta} s_{M_k}(e^{i \theta} )| = 2 \left| \sum_{r=1}^{M_k} \frac{\sin (r \theta)}{r} \right|$ and so, by the lemma, is bounded independently of $\theta$. The $\frac{1}{k^2}$ factor in front then forces uniform convergence.

We now prove the lemma. This is the only part I'm not adapting from Pinsky, because he treats this as obvious.

**Proof of lemma:** Since the sum of sines is clearly periodic modulo $2 \pi$, and is clearly odd, we may assume that $\theta \in (0,\pi)$. We break the sum at $r=K$, for a parameter $K$ to be chosen later. For the first part of the sum,
$$\left| \sum_{r=1}^{K} \frac{\sin (r \theta)}{r} \right| \leq \sum_{r=1}^{K} \frac{r \theta}{r} = K \theta.$$

For the second part of the sum, we start by noting
$$\sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cdot  \sum_{r=K+1}^M \frac{\sin (r \theta)}{r} = $$
$$\frac{\cos ((K+1/2) \theta)}{K+1} + \sum_{r=K+2}^M \cos ((r-1/2) \theta)\left(   \frac{1}{r-1} - \frac{1}{r} \right)+ \frac{\cos((M+1/2) \theta)}{M}$$
so
$$\left| \sum_{r=K+1}^M \frac{\sin (r \theta)}{r} \right| \leq  \frac{1}{\sin (\theta/2)} \left( \frac{1}{K+1} +  \sum_{r=K+2}^M \left(   \frac{1}{r-1} - \frac{1}{r} \right)+ \frac{1}{M}\right) $$
$$ = \frac{2}{\sin (\theta/2) (K+1)} \leq \frac{2}{(K+1)(\theta/\pi)} = \frac{2 \pi}{(K+1)\theta}.$$
We have used the bound $\sin (\theta/2) \geq \theta/\pi$ for $\theta \in (0 , \pi)$, which is true because $\sin$ is concave.

In short, 
$$\left| \sum_{r=1}^M \frac{\sin (r \theta)}{r} \right| \leq K \theta + \frac{2 \pi}{(K+1) \theta}.$$
Choose $K$ such that $K \theta$ is neither near $0$ nor $\infty$, and this quantity will be bounded, so we have proved the lemma. $\square$.

Comment: The Lemma was an exercise in the 2nd edition of Rudin's *Principles*, but he took it out in the 3rd, while trimming the Fourier series part. Too bad. // His approach was: (i) the Fourier series of any function of bounded variation has uniformly bounded partial sums; (ii) $\sum \sin(r\theta)/r$ is the Fourier series of $\pi-t$ on $(0,\pi)$, extended to $(-\pi, \pi)$ as an odd function. // The idea of (i): BV gives $c_n=O(1/n)$ for the coefficients, which is enough to bound the difference between Fejer and Dirichlet sums. (And Fejer sums are trivially bounded).

Comment: @DavidSpeyer : Could you explain why $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ extends continuously to the boundary?

Comment: @MalikYounsi Because the sum $\sum_k \frac{z^{N_k}}{k^2} S_{M_k}(z)$ is uniformly convergent on the closed disc, so it converges to a continuous function there.

Comment: To emphasize: The sum $\sum_n a_n z^n$ doesn't converge at $1$, but if we group it together into chunks as $\sum_k \frac{z^{N_k}}{k^2} s_{M_k}(z)$, then it converges everywhere on the closed disc.

Comment: (David: It is only one person, Paul du Bois-Reymond)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I did not know that! Thanks.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer : Thanks for the clarification. Another way to formulate this is that $f$ is in fact the Poisson integral of a continuous function on the unit cirle, so $f$ is continuous on the closed unit disk.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Can you provide reference for the construction of du Bois-Reymond since the link you shared is not working?

Answer (score 13):

**Question 1**

In general, no. Consider, for example, $f(z) := \frac{1}{1+z}$. This function has a Taylor series, centred at $z=0$, with radius of convergence $\rho = 1$. We see that $f(z) \equiv 1 - z + z^2 - \cdots + (-1)^kz^k + \cdots $ for all $|z| < 1$. The function $f$ is continuous for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ except $z=-1$. (In fact, $f$ is holomorphic for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ except $z=-1$, which is *much stronger* than just continuous.)

Now, consider the point $z=1$. The function is holomorphic at $z=1$ and $f(1)=1/2$. However, trying to apply the power series at $z=1$ gives the divergent series $1-1+1-1+1-1+\cdots$.

**Question 2**

I know that this isn't what you asked, but there exist power series which converge for all $|z| \le 1$ and yet are discontinuous on the circle $|z|=1{}$. This is a result by Sierpinski (1916).

Comment: Do you mean that Sierpinski's example is nowhere continous on the unit circle? Can you tell  me in which article his example is constructed.

Comment: @WallGreat Sierpinski's example was [thoroughly discussed on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/110345/does-a-power-series-converging-everywhere-on-its-circle-of-convergence-define-a-c)