# Does a bounded convergent power series on an open disc extend to the boundary?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Here is my question: Suppose that $|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n| \leq M$ for all $z \in D_r$ (the open disc or radius $r$). Does this power series converge on $\partial D_r$?

Comment: it is known that if $f(z)$ has no singularities on $D_r$, then $f(z)$ can be extended to a larger disk.

Comment: @Yimin $f(z)=(1-z)^{-1}=\sum z^n$ has no singularities on $D_1$, but it can't be extended to a larger disk. I believe the OP talks about the open disk. If it is the closed disk, the fact is trivial.

Comment: Your question is related to Abel's theorem


   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. There are even functions that are continuous on $\bar D_1$ and analytic  on $D_1$ whose Taylor series diverges for some points on the boundary. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286119)

Comment: And the construction is way more involved than my previous silly counterexample...+1 for find the reference.