# Demonstration of existence of Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-series

Joseph Fourier demonstrated that an arbitrary T-periodic function $f(t)$ can be written as a linear combination of harmonic complex sinusoids:

$$f(t) = \sum_{n=\infty}^\infty c_ne^{iw_ont}$$

(And likewise as $t -> \infty$ or in other words for the case of Fourier Transform, with some limitations).

Where is the proof/demonstration that shows that the series/transform indeed converges to f(t) and thus the identity exists. Further can it be seen that the solution for coefficients $c_n$ are unique from the derivation of the $c_n$. (Derivation: http://cnx.org/contents/8YnJdzjg@8/Derivation-of-Fourier-Coeffici)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so simple: you need some restrictions on the function.  If $f$ is continuous and has bounded variation, the series converges pointwise everywhere to $f(t)$.  But there are continuous functions whose Fourier series diverge at infinitely many points.

Comment: yet It is quite complicated to give explicit counter-examples http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286119/continuity-of-analytic-function-implies-convergence-of-power-series/287854#287854

Comment: @Robert Israel Are you then saying that Fourier assumed the identity... is there a proof for at least the continous bounded variation case?

Comment: Fourier didn't prove much.  He couldn't: most of the concepts of analysis did not exist in his day.  Even the concept of a [function](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Functions.html) was not clear.

Comment: See e.g. [this page](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/jordan-s-and-dini-s-tests-for-convergence-of-a-fourier-serie)